# How can i send confirmation mail send different from address?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets

I'm sending confirmation mail with following code in google docs scripts.

But It is sending from my personal gmail address. I need define different mail address. Cause I will use this for my company and mail need show like that `sometest@companytsite.com`

How can i do that?

My Code:

```
function Initialize() {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendConfirmationMail")
        .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();

}

function SendConfirmationMail(e) {

    try {

        var ss, cc, sendername, subject, columns;
        var message, value, textbody, sender;

        // This is your email address and you will be in the CC
        cc = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

        // This will show up as the sender's name
        sendername = "Your Name Goes Here";

        // Optional but change the following variable
        // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
        subject = "Google Form Successfully Submitted";

        // This is the body of the auto-reply
        message = "We have received your details.<br>Thanks!<br><br>";

        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        columns = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

        // This is the submitter's email address
        sender = e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString();

        // Only include form values that are not blank
        for ( var keys in columns ) {
            var key = columns[keys];
            if ( e.namedValues[key] ) {
                message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "<br />"; 
            }
        }

        textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");

        GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, 
                            {cc: cc, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});

    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)
You should be able to pass in a from in the options.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, {
    from: "sometest@companytsite.com",
    cc: cc, 
    name: sendername, 
    htmlBody: message
});
```

Nb. to avoid confusion `sender` should really be `to`

Now it also says that the email address you want to send it from must be an alias, to check you can print out `getAliases()` to see if it exists. If not you should be able to follow these instructions:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: Hi @WilliamGeorge from: "sometest@companytsite.com" this is not worked for me.

Comment: It needs to be a valid alias on your gmail account. When you set one up, it will ask you to confirm the email address. I think its a security measure to not allow sending from bogus emails. Have you made sure the alias exists ?

Comment: var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
      Logger.log(aliases);
      GmailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, textbody, 
                            {
                             from: "sometest@companytsite.com",
                             cc: cc,
                             name: sendername,
                             htmlBody: message,
                             from: aliases[0] });`


I changed like that but not saving code erroring this line   "sometest@companytsite.com", I used from: "sometest@companytsite.com", and without 'from' i see same error. Yes my mail valid.

Comment: Sorry I was missing a comma at the end of the from line. What error are you seeing?

Comment: Yes i was see it and i was added comma :) so stil erroring same line.

Comment: Hi @ErdalBakkal, did either of you manage to solve this? My "Email address" test entries aren't receiving any emails...